# Has a value increased in a Clojure vector of hashes?

Tags: vector, hash, clojure

Newbie Clojure question alert...

I've got a Clojure vector that looks something like this:

```
(def sample-data
  [{:date "2014-01-01" :value 5}
   {:date "2014-01-02" :value 7}
   {:date "2014-01-03" :value 6}
   {:date "2014-01-04" :value 7}
   {:date "2014-01-07" :value 11}])
```

Actually it's much larger than that, but you get the general idea... - it's a vector of single values, collected once a day.  The vector will be sorted in :date order, but there's gaps for the odd missing sample.

I want to create a function that takes a :date in 'sample-data', and tells me if :value on that date is greater than :value on the preceding date.  Corner cases:

- if there was no sample on the preceding date, then I want to go back to the last date when a sample was collected and compare with that :value instead
- if there's no :value for the specified date, then I'm happy to raise an error and deal with it elsewhere
- if the two :values are equal, I want to return false (because it hasn't increased)

I want to call the function as e.g.

```
(value-increased? sample-data {:date '2014-01-03'})
```

and get a boolean response back.  In this case, it would be false because the value on 2014-01-03 (6) is less than the value for the previous day (7)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn has-value-increased?
  [sample searched-date]
  (reduce (fn [_ [{:keys prev-value :value} {:keys [value date]}]]
            (if (and (= date searched-date)
                     (< prev-value value))
              (reduced true)))
          nil
          (partition 2 1 sample)))
```

Notice that this is probably inefficient as the entire sample could be traversed with each call to the function. Depending on the real-world application it would certainly be better to write a function that collects all dates where the value has increased in *one pass* and returns it e. g. as a set, where you can then invoke it as a function to check whether a date has increased.

Here is the modified function that does that:

```
(defn collect-dates-with-increased-value
  [sample]
  (reduce (fn [acc [{prev-value :value} {:keys [date value]}]]
            (cond-> acc
              (< prev-value value) (conj date)))
          []
          (partition 2 1 sample)))
```

Then collect the dates, e. g. at the REPL:

```
=> (def dates-with-increased-value (set (collect-dates-with-increased-value sample-data)))
=> dates-with-increased-value
#{"2014-01-02" "2014-01-04" "2014-01-07"} 
=> (dates-with-increased-value "2014-01-02")
"2014-01-02"
=> (dates-with-increased-value "2014-01-03")
nil
```

Comment: Gonna go with this answer because it's simple and elegant.  It's actually very useful to me to be able to get the full set of dates-with-increased-value, even though I didn't ask for it - I was going to iterate through all dates, but your approach of doing the calc once and then extracting data out of the resulting set seems to be a particularly good solution.  Thanks

Comment: FYI I simplified the algorithm so that the input sequence no matter of what kind does not need to be reversed.

Answer (score 4):

You could find the index for the given date using binary search, then examine the entries at that index and the preceding one.

Alternatively, you could use mikera's [timeline](https://github.com/mikera/timeline) library which provides a data structure for maintaining exactly this sort of vector-like log of timestamped values and assorted functions operating on such logs:

```
(require '[mikera.timeline :as tl])

(def t
  (-> (tl/timeline)
      ;; (tl/log timestamp value)
      (tl/log 0 0)
      (tl/log 86400000 1)))
```

Then `tl/seek` allows you to find the index of the last entry before the given time, while the entry at the given index can be extracted with `nth`.

Finally, [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) is useful for specifying time (and is already a dependency of timeline):

```
(tl/log (tl/timeline) (clj-time.core/now) :foo)
;= #<Timeline [[#<Instant 2014-02-04T08:00:08.290Z> :foo]]>
```

Comment: Again a nice solution, but not quite as good as the first one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you try this code, you can comment each line from (first..) up to see which step does what.

```
(->>
  sample-data
  (filter :value)
  (map #(assoc % :date (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") (:date %))))
                     ;parse date
  (sort-by :date)
  (partition 2 1)    ;partition the sequence into every two consecutive days that have a :date value
  (map (fn [[f s]]   ;destructure vector into first day f and second day s 
         (conj s [:in-order (< (:value f) (:value s))])))
                     ;compare days, return second date with compare boolean in in :in-order key 
  (remove :in-order) ;filter where :in-order is false
  first              ;take first false :in-order, and stop processing
)
```

Comment: I'd leave the sorting out, otherwise the final zipmap could assign wrong key/vals.

Comment: Your algorithm, as it looks now, will return the hash-map with the earliest date that is immediately followed by a date with a higher value... :O

Comment: Nice, now you could simply return s in the lambda if the comparison turns out true and then use `keep` instead of map. Would get rid of :in-order.

Comment: In the current version I guess you'd have to use `filter` instead of `remove` again.

Comment: I can follow your logic fine and I can see how your solution hangs together, but to my mind it's not the best answer (it's very good though; I just got a bunch of great solutions!).  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use a sorted set instead of a vector? If the collection is actually sorted by date, and Clojure knows about it, you can simply use `get` to look up a particular date, or `subseq`/`rsubseq` to find dates near some goal. Then it's pretty easy to check whatever condition you want about any date you like.

Comment: One of 4 great answers, but not the one I'll go with in this case.  I could munge the data to a sorted set so your solution would work fine, but I think the first answer is the best fit for the problem as I described it.  Thanks